# Android version compatibility for Math.toIntExact Utility method

Tags: java, android, utility

The `Math.toIntExact` method is throwing an exception on my Android 6.0 emulator. (More recent emulator versions are ok)

[This Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.math.tointexact?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) is the only doc I found about it. Am I correct in thinking that `Math.toIntExact` is not compatible before Android 9.0 ?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker, PID: 9527
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method toIntExact(J)I in class Ljava/lang/Math; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Math' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
        at com.dmurphy.remotescrumpoker.Activity_TeamDetails$6.onComplete(Activity_TeamDetails.java:268)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
D/FA: Event not sent since app measurement is disabled
```

Comment: yes you are right, `toIntExact` according android documentation, it was added in API level 24, and require android N or greater to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Math::toIntExact`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact(long)), as per the documentation, has been introduced with API level 24, that is Android 7.0. So yeah, it's not available on Android 6.

The good news is that you can easily implement it yourself by extracting it from the [`java.lang.Math` source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l1009).

```
public static int toIntExact(long value) {
    if ((int)value != value) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return (int)value;
}
```